# Saving Zip Files On iOS via Javascript In The Browser

Tags: javascript, ios, download, zip, jszip

A few years ago I created an app [kodeWeave](http://michaelsboost.github.io/kodeWeave). Now [kodeWeave](http://michaelsboost.github.io/kodeWeave) uses a javascript library called [JSZip](http://stuk.github.io/jszip/) which is used to create and download .zip files client-side.

However, I'm unable to download zip files using JSZip on my iPhone, but if the zip file is located on a server like [Github](https://github.com/michaelsboost/kodeWeave) I can actually download the zip file on my iPhone.

I thought at first it may just be the Chrome browser, however, I tested with other browsers such as Safari, Firefox, Edge, Dolphin Browser and MyMedia. All will open a new blob or blank tab but that's it, it just sits on a blank tab that does nothing.

Because I can download zip files on a server, this issue is specifically related to how JSZip is programmed. So my question comes in two parts.

1) Does anyone know how to solve this issue with JSZip?
and
2) Encase question 1 is not an option at all (at least until Apple improves their technology.  Does anyone know of a way to dynamically save zip files to a server similar to how JSZip saves zip files through a blob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem is not in JSZip but in [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) shown in [example](https://github.com/Stuk/jszip).

In FileSaver README there is a [warning](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js#ios) for iOS.

> saveAs must be run within a user interaction event such as **onTouchDown**
>   or **onClick**; ***setTimeout*** will prevent saveAs from triggering. Due to
>   restrictions in iOS saveAs opens in a **new window** instead of
>   downloading, if you want this fixed please tell Apple how this bug is
>   affecting you.

Please also note other browsers support and their limitations for your application.

1. It is not an issue of JSZip. FileSaver can't be fixed in iOS due limitation of system.
   *I am suggesting you to upload temp zip file to backend and provide download link to end users.*

**How to do that?** I modified example from JSZip official website. As HTTP client I prefer **axios**, but you go with vanilla XMLHttpRequest or fetch.

```
var zip = new JSZip();
zip.file("Hello.txt", "Hello World\n");
var img = zip.folder("images");
img.file("smile.gif", imgData, {base64: true});

zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
    .then(function(content) {
        const file = new FormData();
        file.append("blob", content)

        axios.put('/upload/server', file, {})
            .then(function (res) {
              // done
              console.info('Uploaded')
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
              console.error('Failed due', err.message);
            });
});
```

2. There are bugs opened and a patch proposed [Bug 102914](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=102914) opened from 2012 [sic!] and [Bug 167341](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=167341). I believe community can push this fixes to happen.

Comment: Do you know of a way to dynamically save zip files to a server similar to how JSZip saves zip files through a blob?

Comment: I updated my answer. I hope I gave you an exhaustive answer to the question and it would help you with your app.

Comment: Yes it does help